# MYSQL, PHP two connections inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases on the same MYSQL server.

I want to be able to query one table on one database, and use the results for an insert into the other table (on the other data base). I've tried moving the mysql_select_db lines around to no avail. Please note this is a one off internal script so security is not a concern (Don't want to us mysqli)

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$link1 = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password', true)
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
$link2 = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password', true)
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db1', $link1) or die('Could not select database');
mysql_select_db('db2', $link2) or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
$query = "select fields from table";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$querynew = "insert into table (blah,blah) values ('$row['name']',$row['name2']')";
mysql_query($querynew, $link2);
}
```

Comment: Does the username/password have access to both DBs?

Comment: What is the problem you're having with this?

Comment: Despite your insert string is broken and will show T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, you can try different approach, naming databases in the query - `SELECT fields FROM db1.table` ... `INSERT INTO db2.table...`

Comment: Thanks Royal Bg - The insert was an example, which I typed badly! I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @user3329860 think for using mysqli / PDO because mysql_ lib is gone..
Accessing to second DB from the first one is option but its only if you are sure that they will be together with the same user...
If its such case perhaps you can merge them into 1 DB..

Answer (score 3):

You can use plain SQL for this to minimize traffic across the wire:

```
INSERT INTO `db2.tbl1` (`field1`,`field2`)
    SELECT `field1`, `field2` FROM `db1.tbl2` WHERE `someCondition`='IsMet'
```

Comment: Thank you MonkeyZeus and RoyalBG